# C# HttpListener multiple authentication schemes and Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, http, httplistener, www-authenticate

Ok, this is a long question, but I think it worth this. What we have:

1. A sample dummy C# console application, that start self-hosted owin ASP.Net WebAPI service (**`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost`** NuGet package):

   ```
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var url = "http://localhost:8080/";

           Console.WriteLine($"Starting on {url}");
           using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Success! Press any key to stop...");
               Console.ReadKey();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. OWIN startup class:

   ```
   class Startup
   {
       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
       {
           // enable Windows AND Anonymous authentication
           var listener = app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"] as HttpListener;
           listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous |
               AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;

           // configure WebAPI
           var config = new HttpConfiguration();
           config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

           app.UseWebApi(config);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Sample WebAPI controller with two public methods:

   ```
   [RoutePrefix("sample"), Authorize]
   public class SampleController : ApiController
   {
       [Route("public"), AllowAnonymous]
       public object GetPublicSample()
       {
           var message = $"Hi there, mr. {User?.Identity?.Name ?? "ANONYMOUS"}";
           return new { sample = 0, message };
       }

       [Route("protected")]
       public object GetProtectedSample()
       {
           var message = $"Hi there, mr. {User?.Identity?.Name ?? "ANONYMOUS"}";
           return new { sample = 42, message };
       }
   }
   ```

Now, when we run our project and point chrome to http://localhost:8080/sample/public this request is invoked:

```
GET /sample/public HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 50
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 08:05:56 GMT

{"sample":0,"message":"Hi there, mr. ANONYMOUS"}
```

But when we go to http://localhost:8080/sample/protected we have this:

```
GET /sample/protected HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 08:19:01 GMT
www-authenticate: Negotiate,NTLM
server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
content-length: 61
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

And this is almost "as expected" except 1 thing. I expect that when my browser receives 401 HTTP response with `www-authenticate` header(s), he will try to repeate same request with specified authentication (if there where no any other Authorization header in request). But he does not, for some reason:(

To make things more intresting, we can see that **`AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication`** is actualy **`AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm`** and when I remove one of them things starts to work as expected! For example: replace **`IntegratedWindowsAuthentication`** with **`Negotiate`** in our Startup class and head your brouser to http://localhost:8080/sample/protected

```
GET /sample/protected HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 08:29:55 GMT
www-authenticate: tOkeN1231351234153=
server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
content-length: 59
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"sample":42,"message":"Hi there, mr. DOMAIN\\username"}
```

Generally, our server first response with 401 HTTP status and set header **`www-authenticate: Negotiate`** and then browser repeat request with additional Authorization header. Same thing if we replace **`IntegratedWindowsAuthentication`** with **`Ntlm`**.

And one more example to make things clearer. If we remove **`AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous`** and leave only **`AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication`** we will notice 2 things in result:

1. `/sample/public` endpoint is not available for anonymous requests anymore (as expected)
2. `/sample/protected` endpoint now working as it should **(!)**

And if we look at first 401 server response, we will notice that there is two www-authenticate headers instead of one (as before):

```
GET /sample/protected HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 08:44:04 GMT
```

So, my questions is: Is it "OK" to put multiple authentication schemes in single **`www-authenticate`** header? If "Yes, it's OK", why my chrome not nandling this situation? If "No! it's all way wrong!", why `HttpListener` act like this and how can I bypass this? Pls hlp!

Comment: I don't see any reason for people to downvote this question so much. Especially without any comment. Leaving one myself, I found this question both helpful and interesting.

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked a while back, but I'd like to provide my .02. The AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication is a bit strange. IWA is the same as setting Negotiate **and** NTLM. Negotiate, on the other hand, will fall back to NTLM if Kerberos fails. ASP.NET Core doesn't have IWA in the enum: [See ASP.NET Core AuthenticationSchemes Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.net.http.server.authenticationschemes?view=aspnetcore-1.1)

I use:

```
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
```

Comment: This enum is from another namespace: [see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.authenticationschemes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Also, it maybe unclear, but my question is about "why `www-authenticate: Negotiate,NTLM` is not working on chrome, but `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate AND WWW-Authenticate: NTLM` works?"

Comment: But **Core** is a different story.